# Kaltura HTML5 VAST/VPAID player doesn't pass AdParameters to InitAd in CreativeData parameter

Tags: html, kaltura, vast

I have a Kaltura Html5 player embedded in a web page. The player is configured to use VAST/VPAID and a VAST tag is provided which returns the following:

```
<VAST xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="vast_2.0.1-creativeView.xsd">
<Ad>
<InLine id="Viewbix">
<AdSystem>Viewbix</AdSystem>
<AdTitle>Viewbix VPAID Ad</AdTitle>
<Creatives>
<Creative sequence="1">
<Linear>
<Duration>00:04:41</Duration>
<MediaFiles>
<MediaFile delivery="progressive" type="application/javascript" width="224" height="398" apiFramework="VPAID">
<![CDATA[
http://localwww.viewbix.com/plugins/vpaid.js?layout=fizz&id=73272997-9d10-4c3f-973c-f573959cb47d&debug=true&html5=true
]]>
</MediaFile>
</MediaFiles>
<AdParameters>
<![CDATA[ debug=true&html5=true ]]>
</AdParameters>
</Linear>
</Creative>
</Creatives>
<Error>
<![CDATA[ https://localwww.viewbix.com/tracklog ]]>
</Error>
</InLine>
</Ad>
</VAST>
```

Note that there is an "AdParameters" node. According to the VAST specification, the information in this node is supposed to be passed to the initAd function in the CreativeData parameter, but in the Kaltura implementation, CreativeData contains an object with no properties.

Please note that the Google VAST Inspector page ([here](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/vastinspector) does pass the parameters correctly.

Has anyone been able to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in which AdParameters resulted empty. It should be fixed. Here's the issue if you want to fix it in your own Kaltura player. https://github.com/kaltura/mwEmbed/pull/2040

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to get this to work too, though the player seems to store the AdParameters and all their code is open source on github, so you could always add a fix yourself (AdParameters are saved to 'adConf' variable in the JS). Kaltura Repo: https://github.com/kaltura/mwEmbed

Answer (score 0):

Kaltura player includes Google IMA plugin too - you can use it and set as adTagURL the vast XML